# Can an aws IAM policy dynamically refer to the logged in username?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am trying to write an IAM policy which will control access to EC2 instances. All EC2 instances will have a custom tag called username and only if the tag value matches the logged in user's user name, will that user have access to that EC2 instance. This is what I came up with:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-12",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/username": "arn:aws:iam::account-number-without-hyphens:user/username1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am sure you see the problem here. I don't want to hard code the username value on the right hand side. I want to be able to get that information at runtime or policy evaluation time.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The IAM user can be referred to in policy documents by `${aws:username}`.

There is a list of other IAM policy variables and their uses here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PolicyVariables.html

Comment: I just spent too many hours learning this the hard way -- If the policy is attached to any type of IAM entity other than a user, the variable will be "not present" and invalidate the whole statement containing the reference to the variable. This is mentioned on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#principaltable "not present means that the value is not in the current request information, and any attempt to match it fails and causes the statement to be invalid."