# aws policy variable ${aws:username} returning error not authorized

Tags: amazon-web-services, policy, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I have followed the docs at aws http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PolicyVariables.html

and the question at [Can an aws IAM policy dynamically refer to the logged in username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120204/can-an-aws-iam-policy-dynamically-refer-to-the-logged-in-username/23121081#23121081)

to create a policy for a user to list his own credentials under web console/users so he can generate his own keys.

`user/Alpha`

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action":["iam:*"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:iam::{myacctnumber}:user/${aws:username}"]
    }
  ]
}
```

when I attach the the policy to `user/Alpha`, then open a new browser and log in as user Alpha > console > users, I get the error message

```
We encountered the following errors while processing your request
X User: arn:aws:iam::{myacctnumber}:user/Alpha is not authorized to perform: iam ListUsers on resource: arn:aws:iam::{myacctnumber}:user/
```

note the `user/` is not displaying the friendly name as would be expected from ${aws:username}.

I have also tried changing the policy to

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action":["iam:*"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:iam::{myacctnumber}:user/Alpha"]
    }
  ]
}
```

but the same error displays.

If I make one further change to the resource and make it a wildcard,

```
 "Resource":["arn:aws:iam::{myacctnumber}:user/*"]
```

the full user list is displayed to to the user `Alpha`

Do I need extra permissions to allow a user to see only themselves?

thx
Art

Answer (score 0):

The console, when displaying a list of users, uses the `iam:ListUsers` API call. This call cannot be restricted by resource.

Therefore, the console will function correctly if you provide a policies that permits the `ListUsers` call, eg:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListUsers"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The only other way for the user to update their own settings would be via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or an API call, since they can avoid the need to call `ListUsers`.