# Allow AWS users to create their own first access key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want my AWS IAM users that belong to a specific group to be able to manage their own credentials, including the creation of their first access key. It is a requirement that they don't get other permissions such as listing the account's users.

It seems that console access is not an option as it needs permissions I don't want to grant (such as ListUsers).

Thus I tried the AWS CLI option and added the following policy, as advised in AWS documentation.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "iam:*LoginProfile",
      "iam:*AccessKey*",
      "iam:*SSHPublicKey*"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:user/${aws:username}"
  }
}
```

This works well, except that it seems AWS CLI requires an access key to login (which my users don't have yet, I want them to create their access key themselves).

As a work around, I create the access key for them, and then ask them to change it, but it's quite cumbersome.

Is there a way to log into AWS CLI with the user name and password? Is there another way to achieve my use case?

Comment: The restriction against even seeing the *list* of users seems unnecessary, but given that, what if you omit that permission and tell the user with username `example` to log in to the console and then navigate directly to `https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#/users/example?section=security_credentials`?  It seems like that *might* bypass the need to list the users, and if the user got clever and tampered with the URL, it would fail -- they can only actually view their own details. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_users-self-manage-mfa-and-creds.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot unfortunately this doesn't work, the button for creating api keys is greyed out.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered a similar issue. I want my non root users to be able to change their password and change (create/make inactive/delete) their access key for CLI access. However, those users must *not* be able to list users or display/do anything with other users.

My attempt to achieve the minimal policy is this JSON:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
        "iam:ChangePassword",
        "iam:CreateAccessKey",
        "iam:ListAccessKeys"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Some explanation for AWS noobs like myself:

- I created a custom policy in `IAM > Policies > Create policy`. I picked up the relevant permission, add the resources scope and then assign this permission to my user group.
- `iam:ChangePassword` is obviously the password change permission which is restricted to the current user only by the resource = `"arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"`. Replace `*` with the account Id (without hyphens) if you need to restrict to a specific account.
  As mentioned in AWS doc, `iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy` is required

  Sources:

  - [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_passwords_enable-user-change.html)
  - [SO: Refer to logged user in policies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23121081/4906586)
- `iam:*AccessKey` manage access key for the current user as well:

  - `create` allows the creation of a new key so that admin do not know the key
  - `update` allows *make inactive* action
  - `delete` allows access key deletion as there is a quota of two keys per account